# No gcc 4.2 compiler option in Xcode 4?

Tags: iphone, xcode, xcode4, gcc4

In my Xcode 4 installation, I only have 2 compiler options:

1. Apple LLVM compiler 3.0
2. GCC LLVM 4.2

In many Xcode examples I have seen that GCC 4.2 is shown as a third option, but this simply isn't there. I intentionally did a clean installation of XCode 4. Is there a standard method for adding GCC 4.2 if it's not already there? One of my projects requires that I use GCC (and not GCC LLVM), the other projects I am happy with GCC LLVM, so it's only an issue for that one.

Comment: Thanks @Bavarious , that is exactly the right answer.   Premature question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a way to enable compiling with ***gcc 4.2*** in ***xcode 4.2***.  This is mostly done via command line so when you see lines starting with: `[ 15:30 jon@MacBookPro / ]$`, you need to open up *Terminal.app* and run the command that starts after the `$`.

> No files or directories are *removed* or *deleted* in this process, so it is easy to undo if you need to compile with LLVM in the future.

1. Download - but do **not** install *yet* - [xcode_4.1_for_lion.dmg](https://developer.apple.com/downloads/download.action?path=Developer_Tools/xcode_4.1_for_lion/xcode_4.1_for_lion.dmg) or [xcode_4.1_for_snow_leopard.dmg](https://developer.apple.com/downloads/download.action?path=Developer_Tools/xcode_4.1_for_snow_leopard_21110/xcode_4.1_for_snow_leopard.dmg)
2. Now, follow these steps to install Xcode 4.1 into `/Developer-4.1`:

   1. Backup the working `/Developer` directory (where Xcode 4.2 is installed)
     ```bsh
     [ 15:30 jon@MacBookPro / ]$ sudo mv -v /Developer /Developer-4.2
     ```
3. Run the Xcode 4.1 installer using the default install location (`/Developer`)
4. Move the new Xcode 4.1 installation to `/Developer-4.1`:

   ```bsh
   [ 15:30 jon@MacBookPro / ]$ sudo mv -v /Developer /Developer-4.1
   ```
5. Move the Xcode 4.2 developer directory back to `/Developer`:

   ```bsh
   [ 15:30 jon@MacBookPro / ]$ sudo mv -v /Developer-4.2 /Developer
   ```

Edit the Xcode 4.2 `GCC 4.2.xcspec` file to get gcc 4.2 to show in the list of compiler options <sup>[1]</sup>:

```bsh
[ 15:30 jon@MacBookPro / ]$ sudo vi "/Developer/Library/Xcode/PrivatePlugIns/Xcode3Core.ideplugin/Contents/SharedSupport/Developer/Library/Xcode/Plug-ins/GCC 4.2 (Plausible Blocks).xcplugin/Contents/Resources/GCC 4.2.xcspec"
```

- Change lines **41** and **42** from this:

  ```bsh
  ShowInCompilerSelectionPopup = NO;
  IsNoLongerSupported = YES;
  ```
- To This:

  ```bsh
  ShowInCompilerSelectionPopup = YES; 
  IsNoLongerSupported = NO;
  ```

Backup the Xcode 4.2 iOS/Simulator Framework `usr` directories:

```bsh
[ 15:30 jon@MacBookPro / ]$ sudo mv -v /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr.backup
[ 15:30 jon@MacBookPro / ]$ sudo mv -v /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr.backup
```

Copy Xcode 4.1 iOS/Simulator Framework `usr` directories to Xcode 4.2:

```bsh
[ 15:30 jon@MacBookPro / ]$ sudo cp -rv /Developer-4.1/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr
[ 15:30 jon@MacBookPro / ]$ sudo cp -rv /Developer-4.1/usr /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr
```

Copy the `gcc` and `info` iOS SDK library directories from Xcode 4.1 to Xcode 4.2 <sup>[2]</sup>:

```bsh
[ 15:30 jon@MacBookPro / ]$ sudo cp -rv /Developer-4.1/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS4.3.sdk/usr/lib/gcc /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS5.0.sdk/usr/lib/gcc
[ 15:30 jon@MacBookPro / ]$ sudo cp -rv /Developer-4.1/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS4.3.sdk/usr/lib/info /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS5.0.sdk/usr/lib/info
```

**Compile using gcc-4.2!**

[image: Screenshot of CGG 4.2 in xcode 4.2]

**[This is a blog post I've written with a little more info about this process.  Feel free to leave a comment on the blog if you run into any issues or have any questions.](http://blog.hozbox.com/2011/11/08/how-to-use-gcc-4-2-with-xcode-4-2/)**

---

<sup>[1]</sup> If opening from a command line (using something like `vi`, `emacs`, `nano`, etc) make sure to either enclose the path in quotes <kbd>"/long path/with spaces/in it/file.xcspec"</kbd> or escape the spaces <kbd>/some/long\ path/with\ spaces/in\ it/file.xcspec</kbd>

<sup>[2]</sup> This is necessary because the iPhoneOS.platform SDK has its own seperate `/usr/lib` directories but the iPhoneSimulator.platform SDK does not

Answer (score 0):

Xcode 4.3 has a specific folder `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains`.

Is there a way to add other tool-chains as AVR-gcc and PIC32-gcc?