# Adding gcc 4.9 as a compiler option in Xcode

Tags: xcode4.6.3, gcc4.9

I just installed gcc 4.9 (with C11 support), and want to add it to Xcode 4.6.3's build options as a compiler option. I ran `make` and `make install`, and the packages are all there (under `/usr/bin/gcc`. Running `gcc --version` confirms that gcc 4.9 is installed rather than an older version.

When I go into an existing Xcode project's build settings, the only compiler options available are

- Apple LLVM compiler 4.2
- LLVM GCC 4.2
- Other...

Clearly, GCC 4.9 would have to be added using the "Other..." option, although I'm not sure how. I've tried inputting the path to gcc (`/usr/bin/gcc`), although the default value for other isn't a path at all: `com.apple.compilers.llvmgcc42`.

I've also tried following the instructions from the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7531881/no-gcc-4-2-compiler-option-in-xcode-4) as well, but the machine I'm on doesn't have the `/Developer` directory at all, since I believe Apple integrated the developer tools that required (and created) this directory into Xcode.

How do I add gcc 4.9 as a compiler option in Xcode?